# Salary Calculator: How many hours per week?

Tags: discussion, salary-calculator

How many hours per week are the figures based on? It's like specifing the power of an electrical equipment in Ampere or Volts instead of Watts. I hope, I didn't miss it!

Comment: Probably the country’s mean full time, since that’s the most comparable number. This seems like the natural unit. Unless you work in consulting, salary is rarely calculated/displayed/compared per hour: it’s compared as monthly or yearly salary. Case in point, I don’t even know my hourly wage without calculating it: it’s simply not a relevant number.

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks that working a 40h week for 60k and working a 60h week for 60k makes a difference (I am not talking about the number in your contract)? Of course, assuming the mean is an option, but that reduces the amount of information of the salary-calculator to near zero... I feel like half the information is missing.

Comment: No. Literally everybody is thinking this. Conversely, I don’t know of a civilised country where 60h/week contracts would be legal so that’s a complete straw man. If you want to know the hourly wage, just divide the salary by 52 weeks and divide that by the country’s full time weekly working hours. You claim that there’s a reduction in information but the *opposite* is the case: since most salaries are paid as proportions of yearly salaries, this is the raw number. Deriving hourly salaries would potentially lose information.

Comment: If any member of the SO team reads this: Thanks for being heard ;)

Answer (score 6):

We ask for annual income in the developer survey, which is a major part of what's used in the calculation. How many hours worked per week, or even weeks per year are considered can vary greatly from country to country.

What we're after is a rough estimate of the *base*, or the *least* that one working with a certain technology with *n* years of experience might expect.

I think the number of hours worked speaks more to *quality of life* or *work-life balance* than compensation, even though the two are intertwined. You can't escape that, if you're depressed when dividing your compensation by the # of hours worked, you work *way* too much or make way too little, but that doesn't mean you could expect to make *more* elsewhere, perhaps just saner hours more aligned with what you'd expect to work for the compensation being offered.

Say you make $120,000 yearly. that's roughly $2,307.52 weekly given 52 weeks, or $57.60 hourly if you assume a 40 hour week.

But if you're working 80 hours a week, you're only making $28 / hourly, even though you match the average of $120K in your country for a seasoned COBOL programmer.

So you get fed up with that, take a job in LOGO making $41,600 yearly which you assume will be an $8 / hourly pay cut, but you only work 1 hour a week. That's $800 an hour, quite a change from the old gig.

It's an interesting point because quite a few work as hourly consultants where they *do* get to set the rate (instead of just agreeing to a consultant agreement just to get on payroll). So you could do some math based on the annual numbers to come up with a reasonable amount to charge a client in (location) based on the calculated average plus some reasonable overhead.

But, for a *typical* salaried employee, hours worked are a quality of job issue *a bit more* than a compensation issue, while still being very much a comp issue, if that makes sense.

I was there, I freelanced for 10+ years, it was never fun figuring out what I was actually working for at the end of the year when it was time to do the books.

And, if you get a chance to get paid to work with LOGO, take it.

Answer (score 1):

In the US, the normal workday is 9 to 5, or 8 hours a day, and the normal workweek is Monday to Friday, or 5 days a week. Most salary calculators will account for 40 hours per week, but again, it may vary across countries.

But also, bear in mind that salary wages are looked at annually for a reason. A typical workday might not always be constant throughout, as some days you may "work" less hours and other days you might do more.

Comment: "A typical workday might not always be constant throughout [...]" - roger that. Still, most people will be able to roughly estimate the yearly average.

Comment: Offtop: so lunch time is included in work hours?